# Create Discovery Rule for Zabbix Agent

Tags: temperature, rules, sensors, zabbix

I am trying to create a discovery rule to automate task of creating new items for temperature sensors. We have inbuilt key:**sensor[device,sensor,**.
I had added sensor name manually key: **sensor[coretemp-isa-0000,temp3]** this is working fine but I want to create discovery rule so that it automatically creates item if there are multiple sensors. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a [custom low level discovery](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#creating_custom_lld_rules) for that. A script should return list of sensors in a specific JSON format, documented in that page on the Zabbix manual.